# What is causing ghosting UIBarButtonItems in UIToolbar?

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

While implementing iPad-Multitasking in an iOS App, an old Bug reappeared.

[image: UIToolbar with ghosting buttons]

What you are seeing is a `UIToolbar` created and managed by a UINavigationController with button items from the front most viewcontrollers `toolbarItems`. The App is running in the simulator on an iPad Air 2 in the 50/50 multitasking setup. The bug happens, when the app enters the background while multitasking (home button) and then enters foreground again (tap on springboard icon).

I have seen this effect appear before, usually related to rotating the device. The 'workaround' was usually to perform all toolbar changing code in places like `viewWillAppear:` in a block on the main queue.

It looks like another `UIToolbar` is drawn underneath with some offset to the button positions causing this parallax-kind-of effect. The underlying `UINavigationController` and `UISplitViewController` seem to be setup correctly when inspected in the debugger (the viewcontroller stack makes sense etc. pp.)

Since this bug has regressed before in my app, I would really like to understand what is going on here to actually fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it.

When reconfiguring the user interface reacting to trait collection changes, I moved `UIBarButtonsItems` from the `navigationItem` to the 'toolbarItems'.

There was one code path, where I did not removed the buttons from the toolbar before adding them to the navbar. This lead to duplicate buttons in the toolbar afterwards. The duplicates were `UINavigationButton` objects, which seems to be the internal representation of buttons in `UINavigationBar` and which don't really belong in the `UIToolbar`.